# Prove $S_{n}$ is a group action on $X={i,j}$ where i is not equal to j and they belong to the set $X={1,2,3,4,5}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

This is the task im trying to solve:
[image]

This seems so obvious. Axiom 1 where $f(e,{i,j})={i,j}$ is clearly right, since e is just the identity permutation, but i have no idea how to prove it formally. Do i just explain how the identity permutation works?

Same with axiom two. Permutations act transitively, i understand that. I just dont know how to formalize it.

Comment: You are overthinking this. "Formally" here means simply "tell your instructor why you know it is true".

Comment: There is nothing to tell. Everything just follows by definition of how the permutation set works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to prove that $\sigma\in S_5 \wedge \{i,j\}\in X\Rightarrow \{\sigma(i),\sigma(j)\}\in X$, and this is true because by injectivity:

$$\sigma\in S_5\wedge \{i,j\}\in X \Rightarrow \sigma(i)\ne\sigma(j)\Rightarrow \{\sigma(i),\sigma(j)\}\in X  \tag 1$$

Then, you have to prove that $\iota_{S_5}\cdot \{i,j\}=\{i,j\}, \forall\{i,j\}\in X$, and this is true because:

$$\iota_{S_5}\cdot \{i,j\}=\{\iota_{S_5}(i),\iota_{S_5}(j)\}=\{i,j\}, \forall\{i,j\}\in X \tag 2$$

Finally, you have to prove that $(\sigma\tau)\cdot\{i,j\}=\sigma\cdot(\tau\cdot\{i,j\}),\forall \sigma,\tau\in S_5, \forall \{i,j\}\in X$, and this is true because:

\begin{alignat}{1}
(\sigma\tau)\cdot\{i,j\}&=\{(\sigma\tau)(i),(\sigma\tau)(j)\} \\
&=\{\sigma(\tau(i)),\sigma(\tau(j))\} \\
&=\sigma\cdot\{\tau(i),\tau(j)\} \\
&=\sigma\cdot(\tau\cdot\{i,j\})\\
\tag 3
\end{alignat}

So, perhaps just $(1)$ deserved some attention.